# Create, writing, reading SQLite DB on External drive for Windows Iot

Tags: c#, sqlite, file-permissions, windows-iot-core-10

I have a Raspberyy Pi3 device.

I am using VS2017 c#.

I am using Windows Iot Core.

I have attached a USB drive to my Pi box.

I am trying to open/create sqlite db on it.

I get cannot open error.

If I switch the DB path to my SD card it works.

So, is it possible to have my .db file on an external usb drive and of so how?

Thanks

My Code:

```
public static async Task<string> GetUsbPath()
{
    var removableDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
    var externalDrives = await removableDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
    var usbDrive = externalDrives.FirstOrDefault(e => e.DisplayName.Contains("Data"));
    return usbDrive != null ? usbDrive.Path : string.Empty;
}
```

n.b
this will return "d:\"

calling code:

```
var path = Path.Combine(GetUsbPath().Result, "db.db");
Connector = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
```

this will return 'sqlite cannotopen' error...

n.b.
In my package.asppxmanifest file I have enabled 'Removable Storage'.

Comment: What's your app type and which SQLite library do you use?

Comment: hi, background app and i am using the uwp iib. Like i said it works if db is on sd card so it is just down to access permissions to the usb

Comment: Have you test the USB drive on desktop?

Comment: yes, 1st thing i did

Comment: If you used SQLite.Net-PCL in UWP, I can reproduce your issue on deskop. So it is not windows iot core specific issue. You can open an issue on [SQLite.Net-PCL GitHub repo](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT well thought out. I will do so. Thanks